# Android: Error while sharing PDF using WhatsApp

Tags: android, pdf

My application was sharing the PDF created by WhatsApp, however after some update it now shows a message: sharing failed, please try again

Sharing by email still works which has this code:
`intent.setType("text/plain");`
Ive seen some solution about it however in this case i need to share the PDF file.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {Firebase.getFirebaseAuth().getCurrentUser().getEmail()});
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report PDF");
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "BODY TEXT by App Didier");
                            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                            if (bundle != null) {
                                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(bundle.getString("pdfPath", "")));
                                startActivity(shareIntent);
                            }
```

I expect to share de PDF file on WhatsApp

Comment: What is the value of `bundle.getString("pdfPath", ""))`? In other words, what sort of `Uri` are you trying to put into `EXTRA_STREAM`?

Comment: thats a path of my file previous created by the app

Comment: That's not going to work. `Uri.parse()` does not parse paths. Even if you wound up with a `file` `Uri`, those have been banned on Android 7.0+, and many apps no longer bother to support them. Use `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Ive ended up fixing by doing with this code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

and adding this to function onCreate:

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

I hope that helps someone with the same issue.